# Generate random scientific notation float in python

Tags: python, random

I want to generate random floats printed in scientific notation, between x and y.

I tried this :

```
'%.2E' % random.uniform(1.0e5,3.0e10)
```

But this keeps generating numbers between 1.0e8 and 3.0e10 and never below ! Is there any other way ? I want the generated numbers to be not concentrated only in the upper limit of the domain !

Thank you

Comment: Do you really want a uniform distribution, or do you want something else? Perhaps you'd prefer the logarithm of the output to be uniformly distributed? Note that that would produce a perhaps-surprising concentration of numbers starting with 1. When it comes to probability, intuition is very frequently wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tim already said, the probability for a random number between 1e8 and 1e10 is a lot bigger than those between 1e5 and 1e8, so it’s just that your sample does not contain those—which is absolutely possible.

A simple test can prove that:

```
>>> [random.uniform(1.0e5, 3.0e10) < 1e8 for _ in range(10000)].count(True)
33
```

So there are indeed numbers below 1e8; it’s just that there are very few, less than one percent.

Now, depending on what you are up to, you might just be interested in generating “nice-looking” scientific notations, without the numbers being actually uniformly distributed. In that case, you could get two random numbers, one which determines the coefficient, and one that determines the exponent:

```
'{:.2e}'.format(random.uniform(1.0, 3.0) * 10 ** random.randint(5, 10))
```

As said, this will not yield uniformly distributed random numbers; so depending on your application this might not help at all. But at least the numbers will “*look* more random”.

Answer (score 5):

Rest assured that there will be numbers in the correct range.

Just think about it. How many numbers (let's take integers for simplification) are there between 10<sup>5</sup> and 10<sup>8</sup>?

How many are there between  10<sup>8</sup> and 3*10<sup>10</sup>? Hint: About 300 times as many.